# Spark Performance Issue - Writing to S3

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a AWS Glue job in which I am using pyspark to read a large file (30gb) csv on s3 and then save it as parquet on s3. The job ran for more then 3 hours post which I killed it. Not sure why converting the file format would take so long ? Is spark right tool to do this conversion . below is the code I am using

```
import logging
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import boto3
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext()
    glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
    job = Job(glueContext)
    sqc = SQLContext(sc)

    rdd = (sc. \
            textFile("s3://my-bucket/data.txt")\
                      .flatMap(lambda line: line.split("END")) \
                      .map(lambda x: x.split("|")) \
                      .filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1))
    df=sqc.createDataFrame(rdd)
    #print(df1.head(10))
    print(f'df.rdd.getNumPartitions() - {df.rdd.getNumPartitions()}')
    
    df1.write.mode('overwrite').parquet('s3://my-bucket/processed')
job.commit()
```

Any suggestions for reducing the run time ?

Comment: it's slow because of the rdd operations. Why don't you use `spark.read.csv` instead of `sc.textFile`?

Comment: the row delimiter in my file is 'END' , with spark.read.csv the linesep argument can take the max length of 1 . from the API docs

"lineSepstr, optional
defines the line separator that should be used for parsing. If None is set, it covers all \\r, \\r\\n and \\n. Maximum length is 1 character."

Comment: maybe you can use a cli tool (e.g. sed) to convert all instances of END to \n before feeding the csv files to spark

Comment: that was one thought but sed is going to do one parse on the file. using pyspark I wanted to use the cluster computing resoruces.

Comment: spark indeed allows parallel computation but you're using the Python .split() for this, which is very slow

Comment: Noted - any other way to do it then ? within pyspark . Is it possible that maybe my code is not optimized enough due to which tasks might not be getting split on the worker nodes ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233078/discussion-between-infinite-and-mck).

Comment: its the characters 'END' the file has 4 million lines approx

line1 END
line2 END

Comment: 1. You need to hand off to spark the work of splitting the file by line
2. you need to use an S3-aware committer to write data without renaming;  EMR has one.

Comment: can you please elaborate on your comment